# Adding a new route to an existing Ember.js app, need input

Tags: ember.js

I have an existing Ember app which works great. I need to add a new subroute to the app to allow users to view additional information. My current route looks like this:

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('accounts',  { path: '/accounts' }, function(){
        this.resource('account', { path: ':account_id'});
    });
});
```

with the following URL

```
#/accounts/56/
```

The route I'd like to add is this:

```
#/accounts/56/interactions
```

So I added a nested route like so:

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('accounts',  { path: '/accounts' }, function(){
        this.resource('account', { path: ':account_id'}, function(){
            this.route('interactions', { path: '/interactions'});
        });
    });
```

});

But when that route is accessed I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The route interactions was not found core.libs.js:2236
Uncaught Error: You cannot modify child views while in the inBuffer state core.libs.js:19298
```

So I also added an empty InteractionsRoute but that didn't resolve it:

```
Social.InteractionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend();
```

Does anyone have input on what might be going wrong?

In addition I'm trying to add a button to the interface which looks like this:

```
{{#linkTo "interactions"}}@ Interactions{{/linkTo}}
```

Comment: Did you try it without the / preceding the interactions route: {path: 'interactions'} ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('accounts',  { path: '/accounts' }, function(){
        this.resource('account', { path: ':account_id'}, function(){
            this.route('interactions', { path: '/interactions'});
        });
    });

});
```

Like this the URL to interactions is #/interactions

But you wanted this: #/accounts/56/interactions
Therefore you need to remove the preceding slash in the path hook of interactions, otherwise you'll indicate that this route will be accessed from the root.

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('accounts',  { path: '/accounts' }, function(){
        this.resource('account', { path: ':account_id'}, function(){
            this.route('interactions', { path: 'interactions'});
        });
    });

});
```

By the way, if you don't declare a path hook the url will be the same as the route name. So you can also use this:

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('accounts', function(){
        this.resource('account', { path: ':account_id'}, function(){
            this.route('interactions');
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting out your list from the individual record view.

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('accounts');
  this.resource('account', { path: '/accounts/:account_id' }, function() {
    this.route('interactions');
  });
});
```

Your route name for interactions should be like this:

```
Social.AccountInteractionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend();
```

From the table on http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

If all else fails you could just avoid the nested resources and define the paths for each route.

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('accounts');
  this.resource('account', { path: '/accounts/:account_id' });
  this.resource('account-interactions', { path: '/accounts/:account_id/interactions' });
});
```